# .ebignore not skipping node_modules (Amazon)

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, containers

When I try to run `eb create` (Windows), I get the following error:

```
ERROR: FileNotFoundError :: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: './website\\frontend\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\sass-graph\\node_modules\\yargs\\node_modules\\read-pkg-up\\node_modules\\read-pkg\\node_modules\\normalize-package-data\\node_modules\\is-builtin-module\\node_modules'
```

My .ebignore file looks like this, and also works on the majority of the files:

```
# Project Files
webiste/static/
env/
.idea/
node_modules/
```

If I run `eb create --verbose`, I get the following output: (after skipping my env folder with success)

```
INFO:   -skipping: ./website\frontend\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\sass-graph\node_modules\yargs\node_modules\read-pkg-up\node_modules\read-pkg\node_modules\normalize-package-data\node_modules\hosted-git-info\LICENSE
INFO:   -skipping: ./website\frontend\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\sass-graph\node_modules\yargs\node_modules\read-pkg-up\node_modules\read-pkg\node_modules\normalize-package-data\node_modules\hosted-git-info\package.json
INFO:   -skipping: ./website\frontend\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\sass-graph\node_modules\yargs\node_modules\read-pkg-up\node_modules\read-pkg\node_modules\normalize-package-data\node_modules\hosted-git-info\README.md
INFO:   -skipping: ./website\frontend\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\sass-graph\node_modules\yargs\node_modules\read-pkg-up\node_modules\read-pkg\node_modules\normalize-package-data\node_modules\is-builtin-module\index.js
INFO:   -skipping: ./website\frontend\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\sass-graph\node_modules\yargs\node_modules\read-pkg-up\node_modules\read-pkg\node_modules\normalize-package-data\node_modules\is-builtin-module\license
INFO:  +adding: ./website\frontend\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\sass-graph\node_modules\yargs\node_modules\read-pkg-up\node_modules\read-pkg\node_modules\normalize-package-data\node_modules\is-builtin-module/
INFO:   +adding: ./website\frontend\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\sass-graph\node_modules\yargs\node_modules\read-pkg-up\node_modules\read-pkg\node_modules\normalize-package-data\node_modules\is-builtin-module\node_modules
INFO: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\ebcli\core\ebrun.py", line 45, in run_app
    app.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cement\core\foundation.py", line 797, in run
    return_val = self.controller._dispatch()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cement\core\controller.py", line 472, in _dispatch
    return func()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cement\core\controller.py", line 478, in _dispatch
    return func()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\ebcli\core\abstractcontroller.py", line 60, in default
    self.do_command()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\ebcli\controllers\create.py", line 265, in do_command
    source=source)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\ebcli\operations\createops.py", line 75, in make_new_env
    build_config=build_config)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\ebcli\operations\commonops.py", line 867, in create_app_version
    version_label, source_control, staged=staged)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\ebcli\operations\commonops.py", line 1054, in _zip_up_project
    fileoperations.zip_up_project(file_path, ignore_list=ignore_files)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\ebcli\core\fileoperations.py", line 436, in zip_up_project
    zip_up_folder('./', location, ignore_list=ignore_list)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\ebcli\core\fileoperations.py", line 423, in zip_up_folder
    _zipdir('./', zipf, ignore_list=ignore_list)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\ebcli\core\fileoperations.py", line 493, in _zipdir
    zipf.write(cur_file)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\zipfile.py", line 1322, in write
    st = os.stat(filename)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: './website\\frontend\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\sass-graph\\node_modules\\yargs\\node_modules\\read-pkg-up\\node_modules\\read-pkg\\node_modules\\normalize-package-data\\node_modules\\is-builtin-module\\node_modules'
```

I don't know why it suddenly wants to start adding, even after skipping dozens of node_modules files.

EDIT: I also tried every possible way of formatting, for ex /node_modules, \node_modules, node_modules\, node_modules/**/*, node_modules/* etc..

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I fixed this by ditching the .ebignore and initialized a new git repository with my project in it. Then I made my .ebignore the .gitignore (and deleted the .ebignore). Now I have no errors and files get skipped correctly.

Answer (score 11):

My suggestion is to set `.ebignore` to ignore everything **first**, then include needed directories and files.

I've had the same problem, but after I've added `node_modules` at the **very end** of the `.ebignore` file, the problem was solved.

```
# Ignore everything
*

# Except  
!bin/
!dist/
!whatever/
!Dockerrun.aws.json
!package.json

# Ignore node_modules
node_modules
```

Comment: What's the explanation for ignoring `node_modules` at the end working, as opposed to do it at the start? It works, just wondering why..

Comment: @EvandroPomatti good question, but I don't recall what was the exact reason. Maybe it got something to do with how bundle is created, as mentioned in the 3rd paragraph of [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-ebignore) section: _"When .ebignore is present, the EB CLI doesn't use git commands to create your source bundle."_